# Two TableView in one UITableViewController

Tags: ios, iphone

I need to use two `UITableView` in one `UITableViewController`. And I need to create two custom cell for each `UITableView`.

Can I possible to make this? please help me.

Comment: I would recommend using the same tableview, just load different cells in it.

Comment: Or if you really need two TableView then use two UITableView in one UIViewController

Comment: you can compare tableview in datasource and delegate methods by name or tag, with this you can load your desired data in desired table view.

Comment: You could also create something like a TableViewDataAdapter that takes a reference to a tableview, implement UITableViewDataSource and Delegate, sets itself as such in the TableView and implements the required logic. These adapters are then instatiated in your uiviewcontroller (you no more need the uitableviewcontroller in fact as the important stuff is in the adapters now.) This keeps your controller and design clean, priperly encapsulates responsibilities and allows to inject data in the appropriate "table" by setting a data object in the adapters.

Answer (score 0):

try this.....used two UITableView in one UIViewController...

```
  -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView==self.tableview1)
    {
      return tableview1RowCount;
    }
    else if(tableView==self.tableview2)
    {
      return tableview2RowCount;
    }



}
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if (tableView==self.tableview1)
     {
          static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"tableview1_cell";

          tableview1_cell *cell1 = (tableview1_cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
         if (cell1 == nil)
         {
             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableview1_cell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell1 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
         }
         return cell1;
     }

     if (tableView==self.tableview2)
     {
          static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"tableview2_cell";

          tableview2_cell *cell2 = (tableview2_cell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];
         if (cell2 == nil)
         {
             NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"tableview2_cell" owner:self options:nil];
            cell2 = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
         }
         return cell2;
     }
}
```

and for the method

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

do same as above....separate tableviews with if condition and give actions to each...whatever u want...